# How to let Angular know to leave the font files in the assets folder when it builds the app?

Tags: angular, typescript

Yes, I have set `<base href="./">` in my `index.html` file to be relative... And when I build my Angular project, my fonts will be moved to the root of the `dist` folder, and my `.scss` file starts reading the fonts from there. I like to change this behavior and let my styles to read the font files, still from the `assets` folder, although the paths are relative.

I know one way would be to just put the styles straightly in the `index.html` file. But I was wondering if there's a better way to achieve this? Maybe a setting in the `angular.json` that I'm missing?

This is my `index.html` file:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyProj</title>

  <!-- As you can see I like my base URL to be relative -->
  <base href="./">
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my `styles.scss` file:

```css
/* See? I also like the path to my fonts be relative. */
@font-face {
  font-family: Mine;
  src: url('./assets/fonts/My-Regular.ttf');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Mine;
  src: url('./assets/fonts/My-Bold.ttf');
  font-weight: bold;
}

body {
  font-family: Mine, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

This is my `angular.json` file. As you can see I have set `outputHashing` option to `bundles` because I didn't want Angular to hash my font files (just like how I don't like it to move them to the root folder when it builds the project).

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "cli": {
    "packageManager": "pnpm"
  },
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-proj": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "standalone": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "standalone": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "standalone": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-proj",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "bundles"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-proj:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "my-proj:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-proj:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u share angular.json and *.scss file (with link to font file)?

Comment: Please share required code. If possible create minimal reproducible demo in Stackblitz